# jQuery-Mobile listview plugin without using jQuery-Mobile

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm having the hardest time with this search and resigned to just asking it in general.

I'm wondering if there is a stand-alone jQuery plugin which basically has the same functionality as the jQuery Mobile listview. I'm really looking for similar functionality options (scrollable, count bubbles, thumbnail images/icons, split list), but I don't want to use the rest of the framework or build it all manually.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you want it for mobile application or web application?

Comment: I'm looking to use it for a web app

Comment: Looking for it too... :/

Comment: Never found anything, just had to build my own

Answer (score 0):

[edit on July 2012] download builder is now online : http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

You can select any feature you want and a package is built just for you !